# how to draw Area Chart in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, graph, charts

I want to draw Area Chart in Coldfusion. I know we can integrate with [WebCharts3D](http://www.gpoint.com/) but I don't know how to draw it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't need any answers right now. Because, I've done it by myself.

```
<cfchart 
    chartheight="200" 
    chartwidth="300" 
    xaxistitle="Year" 
    yaxistitle="Month" 
    format="png"> 
    <cfchartseries type="area"> 
        <cfchartdata item="10" value="40"> 
        <cfchartdata item="20" value="50"> 
    </cfchartseries> 
    <cfchartseries type="area"> 
        <cfchartdata item="30" value="80"> 
        <cfchartdata item="40" value="90"> 
    </cfchartseries>     
</cfchart>
```

[Multiple Area Chart in Coldfusion](http://www.ppshein.net/index.cfm/2011/1/22/Multiple-Area-Chart-in-Coldfusion)

Comment: Why didn't you post the solution?

Comment: I've added the solution. Vote up, please.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are looking for a multi-series area chart.

You can create these in CF using the `<cfchart>` tag. Docs are [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_c_05.html) and there are lots of example around if you Google, such as [here](http://www.quackit.com/coldfusion/tutorial/coldfusion_charts.cfm) and [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=graphing_08.html).

As an alternative I'd recommend the [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). It provides a way to create many different chart types and I use it instead of `<cfchart>` where I need to create charts outside of a CF page (such as in an email). Very useful.

Comment: Yap, I've already googled the pages you mention. But, CF area showed for only one value.

Comment: Finally, I found that http://www.ppshein.net/index.cfm/2011/1/22/Multiple-Area-Chart-in-Coldfusion